# Why does translation make no impact in projection for a certain dimension?

Tags: python, opencv, camera-projection

Because the camera is off the floor (z=1.25m), points with z=0 should never project to the center of the image (only at infinity).

However, for z=0 and x=0 all points are projected to exactly the center of the image. Why is that?

Minimal example, with a camera image 512x512 in size (so, `cx=cy=256`), and arbitrary focal lenght:
This

```
r = np.asarray([1.57079633, 0.,   0.])  # 90 degrees 
K = np.asarray([[128.,   0., 256.], 
                [  0., 128., 256.], 
                [  0.,   0.,   1.]])
position = np.asarray([0.,   0.,   1.25])  # 1.25m off the ground

points3d = np.asarray([(0, y, 0) for y in range(1,10)]).astype(float)
points2d = np.squeeze(cv2.projectPoints(points3d, rvec=r, tvec=position, cameraMatrix=K, distCoeffs=None)[0]).round().astype(int)

print(points3d)
print(points2d)
```

outputs

```
points3d
[[0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 3. 0.]
 [0. 4. 0.]
 [0. 5. 0.]
 [0. 6. 0.]
 [0. 7. 0.]
 [0. 8. 0.]
 [0. 9. 0.]]
points2d
[[256 256]
 [256 256]
 [256 256]
 [256 256]
 [256 256]
 [256 256]
 [256 256]
 [256 256]
 [256 256]]
```

Comment: Projection works in both directions, so even points behind the image plane are projected. https://answers.opencv.org/question/20138/projectpoints-fails-with-points-behind-the-camera/

Comment: Yes, in this example, I've chosen only points in front of the image (y>0)

Comment: Z is depth, so if camera is not rotated and camera z is positive, a point (0,0,0) is behind the camera plane

Comment: Here's the opencv coordinate system: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/pinhole_camera_model.png

Answer (score 1):

So it seems `cv2.projectPoints(..., rvec, tvec` first rotates camera by `rvec`, and then translates camera (in that rotated frame) `tvec` following
[image]

Thus, if one wants to represent the camera being off the ground, given this specific `rvec=[1.57079633, 0., 0.]` one needs to alter the 2nd coordinate of `tvec` instead of the third

Namely, setting `position = np.asarray([0.,   0.,   1.25])` outputs

```
points3d
[[0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 3. 0.]
 [0. 4. 0.]
 [0. 5. 0.]
 [0. 6. 0.]
 [0. 7. 0.]
 [0. 8. 0.]
 [0. 9. 0.]]
points2d
[[256 416]
 [256 336]
 [256 309]
 [256 296]
 [256 288]
 [256 283]
 [256 279]
 [256 276]
 [256 274]]
```

that is the expected "*projected points starting at the bottom of the image and moving towards the center, the further the 3D point is*"